# Change column names in list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of dataframes on which I want to change the name of the 2nd column in each dataframe in the list so that it matches the name of the list item that holds it. The code that I have at the moment is:

```
my_list <- list(one = data.frame(a <- 1:5, b <- 1:5), two = data.frame(a <- 1:5, b <- 1:5))
my_list <- lapply(seq_along(names(my_list)), function(x) names(my_list[[x]])[2] <- names(my_list)[x])
```

but my code just replaces the dataframes without me understanding why. Any help would be much appreciated.

I know that I can do this easily with a "for" loop, but I would like to avoid it, hence my question.

Comment: Is the assignment of values in your data.frames for this example or is this what you're doing in your  code? If yes, then just change `<-` with `=`. What is the name you're trying to change _to_?

Comment: Maybe you need `library(data.table); rbindlist(my_list, idcol = "myDataFrameID")` ?

Comment: or `dplyr::bind_rows(my_list, .id = "myDataFrameID")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, loop through data.frames, update column name:

```
# dummy list
my_list <- list(one = data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5), two = data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5))

my_list_updated <-
  lapply(names(my_list), function(i){
  x <- my_list[[ i ]]
  # set 2nd column to a new name
  names(x)[2] <- i
  # return
  x
})

my_list_updated 
# [[1]]
#   a one
# 1 1   1
# 2 2   2
# 3 3   3
# 4 4   4
# 5 5   5
# 
# [[2]]
#   a two
# 1 1   1
# 2 2   2
# 3 3   3
# 4 4   4
# 5 5   5
```

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted your answer. It does what I want in a simple way. Although I still don't understand why my code would not do it.

Answer (score 3):

`setNames` can be convenient here:

```
my_list2 <- lapply(
  names(my_list), 
  function(x) setNames(my_list[[x]], c(names(my_list[[x]])[1], x))
)
```

Or the same using `Map` (which I think is easier to read):

```
my_list2 <- Map(
  function(x, n) setNames(x, c(names(x)[1], n)),
  my_list, names(my_list)
)
```

> ```
> > my_list2
> $one
>   a one
> 1 1   1
> 2 2   2
> 3 3   3
> 4 4   4
> 5 5   5
>
> $two
>   a two
> 1 1   1
> 2 2   2
> 3 3   3
> 4 4   4
> 5 5   5
> ```

A problem of `names<-` is that it returns the name, not the object.

Comment: I would necessarily call that a problem. Rather a feature. :)

Comment: Sure! It just comes up as surprising in the apply family every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

You could to use the super assignment operator:

```
my_list <- list(one = data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5), two = data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5))
lapply(seq_along(names(my_list)), function(x) names(my_list[[x]])[2] <<- names(my_list)[x] )
my_list
```

Comment: You could! But many people would rather avoid this since it can lead to unexpected consequences.